# C# Using InsertCommand with a datagrid of checkboxes

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that is loading a table with one Integer and 5 Bool/Bit columns. The DGV loads these as checkboxes which is fine.

I am using SQLCommandBuilder to automatically generate insert/update strings ([Getting data from a Datagrid back into SQL Server Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140709/getting-data-from-a-datagrid-back-into-sql-server-database))

I have a problem when inserting completely new records. When putting in a new line the checkboxes are unticked but they are set as NULL not false. Currently if I want one to be 'false' then I have to tick it and then untick it.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: How do you add a new line ? Do you do this in code, then why not initialize all fields to false there

Comment: Or if you have a DataTable maybe you can use the `TableNewRow` event to initialize the bit fields

Comment: The user is going to be adding a newline themselves using the datagrid itself. Thanks for the heads up on using an event. I try the RowsAdded event to catch the added rows and set the boxes to false.

Comment: You use a DataTable that is bound to your DataGridView? Then it should be possible to set a default value for the Bool Columns in the DataTable.